# Where does the name “field” come from?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I know in some languages, such as German or Portuguese, the term used to refer to fields is “body”, when translated to English.

So I was wondering where “field” came from. One could also ask where “body” came from in those languages, but since this is an English language website, I suppose the former question is more adequate.

Does anyone have any references?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#History) states: "In 1871 Richard Dedekind introduced, for a set of real or complex numbers that is closed under the four arithmetic operations, the German word Körper, which means "body" or "corpus" (to suggest an organically closed entity). The English term "field" was introduced by Moore (1893)." 1/2

Comment: "*By a field we will mean every infinite system of real or complex numbers so closed in itself and perfect that addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division of any two of these numbers again yields a number of the system.*

— Richard Dedekind, 1871" 2/2

Comment: So it was only after Gauss, right? I mean [Carl Friedirch Gauß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauß) :)

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry for my ignorance, but who is the “Moore” referred to in your answer?

Comment: Says Gauss. Funny.

Comment: @Gauss: [Eliakim Hastings Moore (1862-1932)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._H._Moore)

Comment: @Gauss, if you clicked on the wikipedia link, you might have noticed that (as wikipedia often does) it has citations or further links that tell you more. In this case, citation 21 takes you to [this page](https://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html) where you can ctrl+F for Moore